# Use Flow to update/delete events on Online Sharepoint's Group calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, events

I am new to Flow and SharePoint online.

My online SharePoint site is based on a group which was created in Outlook. This SharePoint site has a group calendar. And there is a SharePoint list of events, the info here is used to populate the calendar. So when a new item is added to the list, a new calendar event is created. The event creation is handled by Flow's 'Office 365 Groups' connector.

But the problem is, this connector does not have the ability to update or delete events if the corresponding items on the SharePoint list has been updated/deleted.

Is there a way to make this happen using Flow?

Answer (score 2):

In the flow you use to create event in outlook calendar, add one more step to store the event id of the event in calendar to the list Item. Then you can create a second flow to the list, when an item is modified, the flow can use the event id to find corresponding event in the calendar. And update the event.

Reference link:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-and-Update-Calendar-Events-triggered-from-a-SharePoint/m-p/187504#M19359